# cocos2d CCAppDelegate issue with swift and didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, swift

Is anyone else having issues running a simple Cocos2d v3.1 on Swift with the xcode 6 beta 5?

```
@UIApplicationMain class AppDelegate : CCAppDelegate, UIApplicationDelegate {

override func application(application: UIApplication!, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary!) -> Bool
{
    setupCocos2dWithOptions([CCSetupShowDebugStats: true])

    return true
}

override func startScene() -> (CCScene)
{
    return HelloWorldScene()
}
```

I'm having the issue with my own project, but I found a sample project on github with the same issue:
https://github.com/chunkyguy/Cocos2dSwift

The didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function has the error:
**Overriding method with selector 'application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:' has incompatible type '(UIApplication!, NSDictionary!) -> Bool'**

Changing the function signature to:

```
override func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]) -> Bool
```

fixes the compiler errors but the app crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the AppDelegate.

Has anyone come across this issue or can suggest a fix?

Answer (score 0):

So I wasn't clearly reading the error message in detail. I was missing out exclamation marks because I copied and pasted the UIApplicationDelegate swift generated headers. I should have entered:

```
override func application(application: UIApplication!, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> Bool
```

Command clicking on UIApplication delegate does show:

```
protocol UIApplicationDelegate : NSObjectProtocol {
... 
optional func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]) -> Bool
```

i.e. without the '!'s